# Session values set outside modx are not accesible in snippet

Tags: captcha, modx, modx-revolution

I am trying to use captcha image in my MODx site which is already built and running. I am able to see captcha image but unfortunately captcha script not able to set session value which can be accessed in modx snippet so i cant match it with entered value. Script to create image is located in modx/assets/captcha/captcha.php.
I have spend almost 3 days solving this problem. I tried different methods to make it work. but nothing works. Is there any solution ?? Someone came around this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formit has a captcha prehook - can you take that snippet apart & see how they do it? In fact, why not just use that instead of rolling your own, it would probably cut down quite a bit of work.

Comment: also - are you calling your snippet cached or uncached? uncached would probably be the way to go here.

Comment: Formit plugin uses reCaptcha plugin which is toooooo complex to identify, so my TL asked me to remove it. Anyways i moved my captcha code to snippet, saved image to file called that file and its working now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

put this in your script as follows:

```
//Start the session so we can store what the security code actually is
session_start();
//Set the session to store the security code
$_SESSION["security_code"] = $security_code;
```

and in the snippet that checks:

```
//Continue the session
session_start();
//Check if the security code and the session value are not blank 
//and if the input text matches the stored text
if ((!empty($_REQUEST["txtCaptcha"]) && !empty($_SESSION["security_code"]))
     && ($_REQUEST["txtCaptcha"] == $_SESSION["security_code"]) ) {
  echo "<h1>Test successful!</h1>";
} else {
  echo "<h1>Test failed! Try again!</h1>";
}
```

But if you use Modx Revolution is more appropriate solution would be to use the component FormIt ( http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/FormIt.Examples.Simple+Contact+Page ), with "Recaptcha" or "Blank NoSpam Field"

Comment: Thanks for looking in to question, I have already tried this. script sets $_SESSION["security_code"] = $security_code; but its just don accessible from modx snippets, Here is same forum question "http://forums.modx.com/thread/76328/cant-get-session-from-another-system?page=2".

Comment: How about of use cookies - setcookie("captcha", md5($captcha), $cookietime); and check md5($_REQUEST["txtCaptcha"])==$_COOKIE["captcha"]